# How to find which row the "unsupported operand type(s) for +: Long Str" happened?

Tags: python, pandas, debugging

I am trying to debugging my program in Python Pandas when I am trying to adding two String columns to create a new Column. The program is having the following Traceback: "unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'str'" After I change the datatype by `df['ColA']=df.ColA.astype(str)`, the problem is solved. Therefore, I think there might be one (or a few) rows have integers. 
I need to find which row is causing the problem as there are several million  rows here.

```
ID colA    colB
1  apple   USA
2  Banana  Japan
3  Pear    5
4  Peach   China

df['ColA_ColB'] = vre_df['ColA'] + "_" + df['ColB']
```

below fix the problem, but i need to know which row is causing the problem (or is not `str`)

```
df['ColA_ColB'] = df['ColA'].astype(str) + "_" + df['ColB'].astype(str)
```

looking for methods to print the row number that ColB is not `str`. (e.g. 3)

To be more clear, how can i generate a subset table that ColB or ColA's value is not String. 
e.g. 
ID colA colB

## 3 Pear 5

An additional question, using the existing dataset, is there a quick way to add an " ' " sign to the numeric rows (e.g. '5) in the dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`applymap` may not be the fastest, but It will make the job done as follows:

```
m = df[['colA', 'colB']].applymap(type).ne(str).any(axis=1)
df[m]

Out[472]:
   ID  colA colB
2   3  Pear    5
```

Comment: @William.Wu: glad I could help :)

Comment: Hi Andy, an additional question, using the existing dataset, is there a quick way to add an " ' " sign to the numeric rows (e.g. '5) in the dataset?

Comment: @William.Wu: you just need assign using `loc`. If the number are in `colB`: `df.loc[m, 'colB'] = "'"+df.loc[m, 'colB'].astype(str)`

Comment: Very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

To know if a variable `var` is a string, just use:

```
if type(var).__name__ == "str":
    ...
```

Comment: the original column has a datatype of "Object", will this still work?

Comment: My idea was to use the condition above on each element of your column `colA` to identify which one is not a `str`.

Answer (score 0):

Expression `rows=vre_df['Col_A']!=vre_df['Col_A'].astype(str)` is `True` when the value in that row is not a string. Respectively, `vre_df.loc[rows]` are the offending rows.

Comment: Thanks, but how can i print the row number or Row ID?